# build an array of array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build an **indexed** array of array's in php, not a key value array of arrays, I keep getting parse error. Can you show me where my mistake is? Why is it that I can set the values of the singly dimensioned arrays but not $ax? Thanks!

```
<?php
class mdArray{
public $a0 = array('10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90');
public $a1 = array('11','21','31','41','51','61','71','81','91');
public $a2 = array('12','22','32','42','52','62','72','82','92');
public $a3 = array('13','23','33','43','53','63','73','83','93');
public $a4 = array('14','24','34','44','54','64','74','84','94');
public $a5 = array('15','25','35','45','55','65','75','85','95');
public $ax = array($a0,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5);
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line has a syntax error?  What is the *exact* error you get?

Comment: @RocketHazmat -  I'd imagine `public $ax = array($a0,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5);` which is dependent on run-time information

Comment: Why don't you do :

    `class mdArray{
        public $ax = array(
            array('10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90'),
            array('11','21','31','41','51','61','71','81','91'),
            array('12','22','32','42','52','62','72','82','92'),
            array('13','23','33','43','53','63','73','83','93'),
            array('14','24','34','44','54','64','74','84','94'),
            array('15','25','35','45','55','65','75','85','95'),
        );
    
    }`

Comment: @RocketHazmat -`Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in - on line 9`

Comment: @MarkBaker I am writing a function that takes small values  to create a string with implode. I add a single charter to the end of the string, I do this for every array, then I implode all the strings together into one string, I'm trying to pass only one parameter into the function

Answer (score 3):

It's probably this line:

```
public $ax = array($a0,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5);
```

You need to do that in your constructor:

```
<?php
    class mdArray{
        public $a0 = array('10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90');
        public $a1 = array('11','21','31','41','51','61','71','81','91');
        public $a2 = array('12','22','32','42','52','62','72','82','92');
        public $a3 = array('13','23','33','43','53','63','73','83','93');
        public $a4 = array('14','24','34','44','54','64','74','84','94');
        public $a5 = array('15','25','35','45','55','65','75','85','95');
        public $ax;

        function __construct(){
            $this->ax = array($this->a0,$this->a1,$this->a2,$this->a3,$this->a4,$this->a5);
        }
    }
?>
```

DOCS: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.